# Google Awareness API Fences

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, google-awareness

Please help me understand why my awareness fence that I have setup does not return a TRUE state for being "Still". I am running the app on my phone and I am "Still", and I have kept the phone "Still" for a while to make sure that their is no delay in the trigger.

Note: My fence is being successfully registered, so it can't be a problem with the api request etc. My broadcast receiver is never triggered as well.

The result of the code below is:

```
I/Awareness: Fence was successfully registered.
I/Awareness: Fence sitting_at_work: 0, was=0
```

Code:

```
AwarenessFence sittingFence = DetectedActivityFence.during(DetectedActivityFence.STILL);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), activityReceiver.class);
            intent.setAction(activityReceiver.ACTION_FENCE);
            myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Awareness.getFenceClient(getContext()).updateFences(new FenceUpdateRequest.Builder()
                    .addFence(activityReceiver.KEY_SITTING_AT_WORK, sittingFence, myPendingIntent)
                    .build())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Log.i("Awareness", "Fence was successfully registered.");

                            Awareness.getFenceClient(getContext())
                                    .queryFences(FenceQueryRequest.forFences(Arrays.asList(activityReceiver.KEY_SITTING_AT_WORK)))
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FenceQueryResponse>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(FenceQueryResponse response) {
                                            FenceStateMap map = response.getFenceStateMap();
                                            for (String fenceKey : map.getFenceKeys()) {
                                                FenceState fenceState = map.getFenceState(fenceKey);
                                                Log.i("Awareness", "Fence " + fenceKey + ": "
                                                        + fenceState.getCurrentState()
                                                        + ", was="
                                                        + fenceState.getPreviousState());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                            Log.e("Awareness", "Could not query fence: " + activityReceiver.KEY_SITTING_AT_WORK);
                                            return;
                                        }
                                    });

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Awareness", "Fence could not be registered: " + e);
                        }
                    });
```

BroadcastReceiver onReceive:

```
if (TextUtils.equals(ACTION_FENCE, intent.getAction())) {
            FenceState fenceState = FenceState.extract(intent);
            Log.d("Awareness", "Detected fence action"); }
```